# How can I remove the decimal places from a decimal Key

Tags: roomle

I have a key that has a type of DECIMAL I'm passing this key to a subcomponent, the vaildvalues are set as 600, 800, 1000 etc. when I pass the key I have to convert it to FLOAT but this adds on .00 to then end but I want to have no trailing Zeros. How do I remove these?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no proper number to string function at the moment. What I usually do at the moment:
`substring(string(number), 0, size(string(number)) - 3)`